# AMAT question cache here

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Suppose that the processor reads cache memory in one clock cycle.In case of cache miss the processor needs 5 clock cycles  to read the information in the main memory.What should be the value of Cache hit rate so that AMAT=2?

We know that

AMAT=Hit time+ (Hit rate)*(Miss penalty)

Hit rate= (AMAT-Hit time)/Miss penalty= (2-1)/6=1/6

I am not sure if miss penalty is 6.I know that miss penalty is the sum of the time taken to read the cache memory and the time needed to read the information from the main memory.Which means that Miss penalty=5 +1=6 .Still something feels off here.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: I will write my solution right now,please dont downvote this.

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound mean after asking you to give more detail. But, really, we're not here to check your calculations for you. If you're not sure if your calculation is correct, think about *why* you're unsure. Is there something you don't understand? Ask a question about *that*, so people can help you learn.

Comment: You are right.I am not sure if miss penalty is 6.I know that miss penalty is the sum of the time taken to read the cache memory and the time needed to read the information from the main memory.Which means that Miss penalty=5 +1=6 .Still something feels off here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are clear from the statement of the quesiton: The hit access time is 1 cycle, while the miss access time is 5 cycles.

But you are not sure if the "miss penalty" is just a different name for the "miss access time", or is it in fact the "miss access time" minus the "hit time", right?

So let's think about this together.

What is this AMAT thingy you are trying to compute?

it is the *Avarage* access time.  (i'd guess AMAT stands for Avarage Memory Access Time, right?).

Let's assume the miss-rate is 1/6. It means that 5/6 of the times, we have a hit, but 1/6 of the times it's a miss. In this case the average access time would be:
$$ \frac56 \times 1 + \frac16 \times 5 = 1 \frac23$$
BUT OH NO! that's not what you got. Note that your formula for AMAT is **not**

> AMAT = (hit-rate)*hit-time + (miss-rate)(miss-time)

but it is (fixing the typo you have there, *miss-rate${}=(1-{}$hit-rate$)$*)

> AMAT = hit-time + (miss-rate)(miss penalty)

But AMAT is just AMAT, which can mean only one thing: for hit you pay "hit-time", and for miss you pay "hit-time + miss-penalty". Again: you always pay the hit, and only if it is a miss, you pay an *extra* of the miss-penalty. Make sure you see that this is exactly what your AMAT formula says.
Therefore, the miss-penalty must be defined as the miss-access-time *minus* the hit-access-time.